# TIDA-01513 Riso calculation

Tags: texas-instruments, leakage-current

Can someone assist with getting the Riso value using the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidudj6/tidudj6.pdf?ts=1648902956306&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Ftool%252FTIDA-01513)

HV_batt = 400V

ISO_NEG = 4.278V

Rns1+Rns2 = 1.2Mohm

Vref = 2.5V

Rs2 = 5kohm

Using the equation TI used, we get Riso = -68110.24 ohms, which is clearly wrong and the expected resistance should be 100kohm.

Does anyone have any experience with using this design that can provide help on how to get Riso?

[image]

Comment: This could just a be typo in your question. For your data you have "Rns1+Rns2" (IE Addition), however the equation has "Rns2-Rns1" (IE Subtraction).

Comment: @Tyler not a typo because it is -Rns2-Rns1 or -(Rns2+Rns1)